# Run MsiExec from PowerShell and get Return Code

Tags: powershell, return-value, exit-code, windows-installer

With `BAT/CMD` script I can simply use `"msiexec /i <whatever.msi> /quiet /norestart"` and then check `%errorlevel%` for the result.

With `VBScript`, using the `Wscript.Shell` object `Run()` method, I can get the result like this:

```
"result = oShell.Run("msiexec /i ...", 1, True)"
```

How can I do this with PowerShell?

Comment: any sample with full source code ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would wrap that up in Start-Process and use the ExitCode property of the resulting process object. For example

```
(Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "<<whatever>>" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for!  However, it's "ArgumentList" not "ArgumentsList", but in any case you answered the question - thank you!

Comment: Notes; 1.Inside the quoted -ArgumentList, arguments are space-delimited and single quotes can be used to hold items like a path with spaces in the name. 2.ExitCode only becomes available if all spawned windows are closed; 3.I'm on PS v4.0.

Comment: If you can't use the quoted `-ArgumentList " '$arg1\ with spaces\' arg2"` you can comma separate multiple arguments `-ArgumentList "$arg1\ with spaces\", arg2`, once it stops finding commas PowerShell assumes the next is another positional argument or if something like `-Wait` it will just resume processing the named arguments.

Answer (score 17):

```
$LastExitCode
```

or

```
$?
```

depending on what you're after. The former is an integer, the latter just a boolean. Furthermore, `$LastExitCode` is only populated for native programs being run, while `$?` generally tells whether the last command run was successful or not – so it will also be set for cmdlets.

```
PS Home:\> cmd /c "echo foo"; $?,$LASTEXITCODE
foo
True
0
PS Home:\> cmd /c "ech foo"; $?,$LASTEXITCODE
'ech' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
False
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the powershell app deployment kit which provides several things.

Then you can use for example

```
Execute-MSI -Action 'Install' -Path "$dirFiles\your.msi" -AddParameters "INSTALLFOLDER=C:\$appFolder"
```

> info http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/