# Powershell Try/Catch or If/Else is not working for my script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, jenkins, try-catch

I have the below `powershell` script which runs from my `Jenkins`:

```
$sqlpackage = Start-Process -FilePath sqlpackage.exe -ArgumentList '/Action:Publish','/SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac"',"/TargetConnectionString:""Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=${Target}""",'/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True' -wait -PassThru -Credential $Cred -RedirectStandardOutput sqlstdout.txt -RedirectStandardError sqlstderr.txt
$sqlpackage.WaitForExit()
$sqlpackage
```

I tried to use the below options for `Try/Catch` or `If/Else`, but so far nothing is working (it goes to the `Else` / `Catch` even thought the script passed successfully:

**OPTION 1**

```
$sqlpackage = Start-Process -FilePath sqlpackage.exe -ArgumentList '/Action:Publish','/SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac"',"/TargetConnectionString:""Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=${Target}""",'/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True' -wait -PassThru -Credential $Cred -RedirectStandardOutput sqlstdout.txt -RedirectStandardError sqlstderr.txt
$sqlpackage.WaitForExit()
$sqlpackage
if ($sqlpackage.LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Get-Content sqlstdout.txt
}
else {
     echo "An error occurred $Error[0]"
     Get-Content sqlstderr.txt
     exit $sqlpackage.LastExitCode
}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
try
{
    $sqlpackage = Start-Process -FilePath sqlpackage.exe -ArgumentList '/Action:Publish','/SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac"',"/TargetConnectionString:""Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=${Target}""",'/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=True' -wait -PassThru -Credential $Cred -RedirectStandardOutput sqlstdout.txt -RedirectStandardError sqlstderr.txt
    $sqlpackage.WaitForExit()
    $sqlpackage
}
catch{
    echo "An error occurred $Error[0]"
    Get-Content sqlstderr.txt
    $LastExitCode = 1
    exit $LastExitCode 
}
```

Can you help me with the correct syntax? eventually the expected behavior is to show `sqlstdout.txt` in case it passed, and `sqlstderr.txt` in case it failed + fail the `jenkins` build.

Comment: _"in case it failed "_  What do you mean by 'failed'?  `try`/`catch` will only work if an exception is thrown.  If the command runs properly, but just doesn't do the thing you wanted, then it isn't much use.  Similarly, with the `LASTEXITCODE` - if the process doesn't return non-zero codes, then that won't work either.  You will need to find a reliable way to determine success/failure and work with that.

Comment: Also add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your commands

Comment: @boxdog I'm pretty sure the `Start-Process` returns `LASTEXITCODE` . @Scepticalist, where exactly? BTW, I've just found this answer, do you think it can help with my case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146198/11705021

Comment: _"do you think it can help with my case?"_  it's impossible to say, since it is not clear what is happening in your scenario.  Is there an exception?  What exit codes are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OPTION 1, the property in the condition of the if block should be `ExitCode`, not `LastExitCode`.